# Facebook search features for finding foreign language "pen pals"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, facebook-messenger

OK, so I know this sounds like it should go in "Language Learners" or some other linguistics type stack, but I feel posting this question here will get some good answers from Facebook power users who know what I am looking for.

**The Question:** I am looking to find people on Facebook with whom would make 'good candidates' for practicing language skills.

**The Problem:** Facebook has grown large, and as such, has become more and more impersonal for those that are not at least 'friends of friends'. Reaching out to random people on a foreign language page asking if they want to practice their English in exchange for practicing their language does not seem efficient. I have looked at groups which are dedicated to learning a particular language, but most of the people in these groups are English learners, which is fine, but not my purpose here.

**Possible Solution:** I could of course just begin commenting, liking, become active on foreign language pages whether or not they are meant for language learning or not, and just try to adapt to the environment. However, posting as 1 of 100 posts is not a quick route to interpersonal communication. I'm sure the process will be exponential as it gains steam, but I'd like to know the best starting point.

**Note:** To those you will comment that this has more to do with social media than a specific web application, this is Facebook specific, and I am asking here because I know Facebook has an abundance of features and there must be some way to expedite what I am trying to do here. Also, I am not finding the French chat rooms... not sure why.

Comment: Sweet. Not sure why I didn't find this. Have you used this site? I'll check it out when I get a chance and post a comment.

Comment: You're probably right. I never intended to intrude on anyone, nor do I even want to go to that trouble. But if there are no other suggestions, this may be a way to connect on facebook via a separate website. Not exactly what I was looking for, but a very good substitute.